# How to do this with Sphinx (limit search results number)

Tags: php, sphinx

I am new to Sphinx, and need some help. I am querying Sphinx server with PHP script like:

```
 $cl = new SphinxClient();
 $cl->SetServer( "host", 9312 );
 $cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY  );
 $result = $cl->Query( "some word",  "index1" );
```

Now I would like to know how to pull for SAME query first 20 results, then next 20 results, etc, like in MySQL `LIMIT 0,20`, then `LIMIT 20,20`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
$offset = 0;
if (isset($_GET['offset'])) {
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];
}
$limit = 30;
$max_matches = 1000;
$cl = new SphinxClient();

$cl->SetLimits((int)$offset,
    // limit for this "page", starting at $offset
    (int)$limit,
    // absolute limit for number of results
    ((int)$limit > $max_matches)
        ? (int)$limit
        : (int)$max_matches);
```

Where `$offset` is the current start record (default 0), `$limit` is the number of records to display per page, and `$max_matches` is the maximum number of matches you want allow returned in a single search.

Answer (score 1):

$cl->SetLimits($ooset, $limit);

http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs#setlimits_offset_limit_max_cutoff

Answer (score 1):

$cl->SetLimits($offset, $limit);

http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs#setlimits_offset_limit_max_cutoff

Answer (score 0):

First time

```
$cl->SetLimits(0,20);
```

then

```
$cl->SetLimits(20,20);
```